# Variable variabls in php using WAMPserver issue

Tags: php, wampserver, variable-variables

I am running newest version of WAMPServer on Windows 7 Home Premium. It accesses database (remote) fine, it runs basic PHP fine. My issue is with variable variables. On my godaddy server, the exact code runs fine.

When I try to include a file that uses variable variables (in this case $state{$i}) in WAMPServer says:

Notice: Undefined variable: state in E:\wamp\www\CCRN411\inc\state_drop_down.inc.php on line 2.

Note that it is looking for state, not state1 as the code generates for $i= 1 which I declare on the first line of the same file.

```
<select class="dropdownState" name="<?php $i=1; echo 'state' . $i; ?>" id="<?php echo 'state' . $i; ?>">
<option value="DL" <?php if ($state{$i} == "DL") {echo ('selected="selected"');} ?>>DELETE</option>
<option value="ZZ" <?php if ($state{$i} == "ZZ") {echo ('selected="selected"');} ?>>NONE</option>
```

If I add

$state1 = . and it is empty.
What is the issue with my variable variable?

Help please.

Comment: It's possible on the godaddy server errors are just disabled, the syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong syntax. You want `${"state$i"}`, as in

```
if (${"state$i"} == "DL") ...
```

Comment: But, the code works on the live server. It generates the proper select and has for more than a year. Why would that be?

Comment: This did solve my issue with WAMP, but not sure why it works on GoDaddy servers. Any thoughts?